# what is a good way to convert Flat structure to hierarchial/tree structure in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a requirement to convert a flat structure to hierarchical. My architecture is as follows:

I get the levels and the parents for each item and want to add this structure to an observable collection to load menu control in my xaml

=======

## Item1

## --Childitem1

## --ChildItem2

## Item2

## --ChildItem3

## ----------ChildItem7

## --ChildItem4

## ----------ChildItem8

## Item3

## --ChildItem5

## --ChildItem6

## ---------------ChildItem9

What is an easy way to do this in C#?

Comment: Could you elaborate some more? How is your data stored at the moment?

Comment: 1. Post your source (flat) data model. 2. Why this question tagged by WPF tag? Do you want to consider any WPF specific?

Comment: I want to add this structure to an observablecollection to load menubar dynamically..sorry will edit my question

Comment: @rapunzel: so, how your *flat* data looks? It is hard to propose any data transformation without knowledge about how this data is represented initially.

Comment: I have started to create a dll with various utilities. One of them is a TreeItem class, which is specifically build to show items in a hierarchical data template (the XAML template is also part of the dll). If you are interested to be a beta tester, I'd be most happy to share.

Comment: @Dennis, my flat data is a new instance of an item with level and its parent, for the item at the root level, parent is 0/null

Comment: @Jan, Yes please, I would like to look at your example, Do you have it some place I can download and test?

Comment: Send an email to jan.grassoft@gmail.com and we'll take it from there as there is no project website (yet).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hierarchical structure like this:

```
class Item
{
   public List<Item> Childs {get; set;}

   // other properties and methods
}
```

If you need a more complex hierarchy with different types of child objects you can use the composite pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Answer (score 0):

This isn't easy.  I code Winforms treeviews all the time.  There are several chunks of code, all of them large.
I create a class called ParentItem, and within ParentItem is a collection of ParentItem(s) named Children.  In short, each element has to be able to contain a list of further instances of itself.
So at some point you might see code like this:

`ParentNode x1 = new ParentNode(1, "Item1"); // constructor contains record Id field and descriptive text`
`x1.Children.Add(new ParentNode(1, "ChildItem1"); // under the presumption the record Id is for a different table`
`x1.Children[0].Children[0].Add(new ParentNode(7, "ChildItem7"); // third level, not 5th level as in your example`

As you add nodes to the treeview control, you will tack children on to children of children.

This is a brief idea, the actual implementation is far more involved.

Comment: What do you have the ID for?

Comment: In my particular case, level 1 was states, linked to a list of states by a primary key in SQL Server.  Level 2 was counties, with a similar key pointing to the corresponding county record in the county table.  Level three was a property in the county, with an Id field pointing to the property record.  Therefore, clicking on the property meant that the code could instantly pull the corresponding record, which it would display on the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: I see. But that makes your class rather specific to one application. If you are looking to create something more general, you could provide a `object Tag` property instead of the numeric ID. After all, your ID is just that: Some arbitrary payload that is attached to your nodes.

Comment: IS Children an ObservableCollection of items?

Comment: I do, in fact, store the respective object in the tag. Lets say that you create a view of: 'StateId, StateName, CountyId, CountyName' and order by StateId and CountyId.  When StateId changes between records you add a node at the state level, which gives you (at that point) an empty list of counties.  If State does not change, you add counties to the last state node you added.  Again, as you point out, the Id field doesn't have to be there, however clicking on the node at some point leads to an object or a record.  An object in the tag could certainly tell you what you just clicked on.

Comment: I haven't done much with the XAML stuff since my work is mostly Winforms.  The examples above related to the treeview control in Winforms and a set of associated classes that I create to populate that treeview.